# Why does calling a method on a shared_ptr in a vector throw a runtime exception?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, runtimeexception

Why does the following code throw

```
Exception thrown at 0x53A5C6DC (nvoglv32.dll) in RenderEngine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0002B174.
```

at runtime and what would be a good solution?

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Static>> statics;

void drawStatics() {
    for (std::shared_ptr<Static> stat: statics) {
        Static *statptr = stat.get();

        statptr->Draw(); //This is what triggers the runtime exception.
    }
}

void addStatic(Mesh &mesh, Texture &texture, Transform transform) {
    statics.push_back(
        std::make_shared<Static>(
            mesh,
            texture,
            transform,
            shader,
            camera
        ));
}

int main() {
    addStatic(playerMesh, playerTexture, platformTransform);
    drawStatics();

    return 0;
}
```

The Static header file is as follows:

```
#pragma once

#include "mesh.h"
#include "texture.h"
#include "transform.h"
#include "camera.h"
#include "shader.h"

class Static {
public:
    Static(Mesh &mesh, Texture &texture, Transform &transform, Shader &shader, Camera &camera);
    ~Static();

    void Draw();

private:
    Mesh *mesh;
    Texture *texture;
    Transform *transform;
    Shader *shader;
    Camera *camera;
};
```

In the Static source file Draw() is implemented as:

```
void Static::Draw() {
    texture->Bind(0);
    shader->Update(*transform, *camera);
    mesh->Draw();
}
```

And the Static constructor and deconstructor as requested:

```
Static::Static(Mesh &mesh, Texture &texture, Transform &transform, Shader &shader, Camera &camera)
    :mesh(&mesh), texture(&texture), transform(&transform), shader(&shader), camera(&camera)
{}

Static::~Static() {}
```

EDIT:
I am using visual studio if that matters.

Comment: It seems the `shared_ptr` wan't initialized correctly.

Comment: Why do you `get()` the pointer? Thats not necessary.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I will include the method that adds the shared_ptr to the vector.

Comment: @Llewv Better yet, provide us with a [MCVE], that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Now the `Static` members, constructor and the `Draw` method.

Comment: Dare I ask for one more thing, the constructor and destructor for `Static`. Sincerely hoping you're not just saving the addresses of those input parameters to those pointers, destroying them later in the destructor. That would have disaster written all over it.

Comment: Your `Transform` (and possibly some other) instance is gone after `addStatic` finishes, so your `Transform *transform` points to free'd memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what you get from throwing pointers and references all over your code and not thinking about lifetimes.

```
void addStatic(Mesh &mesh, Texture &texture, Transform transform) {
```

You take a `Transform` by value, which means, it gets copied, so the function has it's own instance.

```
 std::make_shared<Static>(
            mesh,
            texture,
            transform,
            shader,
            camera
        ));

Static::Static(Mesh &mesh, Texture &texture, Transform &transform, Shader &shader, Camera &camera)
    :mesh(&mesh), texture(&texture), transform(&transform), shader(&shader), camera(&camera)
{}
```

You pass a reference to the local variable to `Static::Static`, take the pointer of it and store the pointer. `addStatic` returns, the local `Transform` gets destroyed and you end up with a dangling pointer to a free'd chunk of memory in your `Transform*`.

Not sure about your other pointers, but you take everything as reference, so please check, when they are going to be destroyed, the other pointers might point to free'd space aswell.

---

By the way:

```
Static *statptr = stat.get();
statptr->Draw();
```

You don't need to `get()` the pointer. C++'s smart pointers behave (almost) like the raw pointers, so

```
stat->Draw();
```

works.

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting used to having to deal with pointers as I am used to Java.